# Is it possible to migrate all forum post and user data from Simple:Press wordpress plugin to Vanilla Forums?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to migrate our forum system from Simple:Press ( a Wordpress forum plugin ) to Vanilla Forums ( open source version running on our own system ). We have quite a bit of existing post data and user data that we would like to keep.

so my question: How can we successfully migrate from Simple Press to Vanilla Forums?

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: It's always possible... just find out what fields the destination wants that the target wants, populate the rest with dummy data or the like, and you're done!

Comment: We can't. If we could, we would not have asked the question. Any more questions?

Comment: Check this out: http://vanillaforums.com/blog/help/importing-data/